# Como converter uma view para string no controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Gostaria de converter essa `view` para `string` e ter o valor em `string` em meu `controller`

O problema é que eu gostaria que ela executasse um trecho de `script` que está nessa `view`

O método atual que tenho, apenas converte, sem executar o `script` que está nessa `view`
Atualmente está assim:

```
  public static string PartialViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
      {
        viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
      }

      controller.ViewData.Model = model;

      using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
      {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, stringWriter);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
      }
    }
```

Em meu controller chamo:

```
var htmlString = helper.PartialViewToString(this,"NomeView",model);
```

Comment: O que seria esses "scripts"? JavaScripts?

Comment: Porque é que precisas da view em string no controller? Isso é um requisito muuiito estranho... Tenho quase a certeza que existe uma maneira melhor de resolver o teu problema.

Comment: Olá, sim "scripts" são os javascripts

Comment: @dcastro, você já viu a lib "rotativa" que rendeniza a view em pdf ? então, a ideia é a mesma, entretanto eu quero armazenar o byte[]

Comment: Ok, parece-me um caso de uso valido. E o que é que os scripts fariam que fosse relevante para a geração do PDF?

Comment: @dcastro é montado usando template engine em js, usando dados que vem via json

Comment: Ou seja, a view que é inicialmente enviada para o cliente não contém dados, e estes dados são mais tarde obtidos via AJAX? Nesse caso, acho que vais precisar de uma view diferente para gerar o PDF, uma view criada na hora com todos os dados necessários .

Comment: sim, foi por esse motivo que eu quero captura-la no controller

Comment: É, acho que o melhor mesmo é criar uma view sem javascript para o PDF :/ coloquei na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Os scripts na view só são executados do lado do cliente - no browser - depois do HTML ter sido gerado e enviado para o cliente.

Vais precisar de outra view sem javascript para gerar o PDF. Até existem javascript engines para correr do lado do servidor, mas acho que isso seria desnecessário, seria considerado um "hack", e sem duvida iria afectar a performance do servidor.